# How to set required_if in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I have two textboxes `color_name[]` and `color_code[]`,

[image: colors]

How to put `required_if`? If the color code is not empty, the color name is required.

```
'color_name' => 'required_if:color_code',
```

error

> Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters.

Comment: I think you need `required_with:color_code` not `required_if:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'color_name' => 'required_with:color_code',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
   return  $validator->errors()->first();
}
```

Use this to solve the problem.

For array please re shape your array into this

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "color_name" => "red"
    "color_code" => "#77"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "color_name" => "blue"
    "color_code" => "#88"
  ]
]


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'color'=>'array',
    'color.*.color_name' => 'required_with:color.*.color_code',
]);
```

Comment: @irankhostravi I have updated based on your array dependency